# Django {{ MEDIA_URL }} blank @DEPRECATED

Tags: django, django-templates, media-url

I have banged my head over this for the last few hours.
I can not get {{ MEDIA_URL }} to show up

in settings.py

```
..
MEDIA_URL = 'http://10.10.0.106/ame/'
..
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
  "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
  "django.core.context_processors.media",
)
..
```

in my view i have

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from ame.Question.models import Question

def latest(request):
  Question_latest_ten = Question.objects.all().order_by('pub_date')[:10]
  p = get_object_or_404(Question_latest_ten)
  return render_to_response('Question/latest.html', {'latest': p})
```

then i have a base.html and Question/latest.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<img class="hl" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/images/avatar.jpg" /></a>
```

but MEDIA_URL shows up blank, i thought this is how its suppose to work but maybe I am wrong.

**Update**
Latest version fixes these problems.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Adding media template context processor also gets the job done

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
)
```

Comment: Ya this was when it was like 1.2 or 1.3. Your method is the correct way now. Also back then the separation between STATIC and MEDIA were not clear as well.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works like a charm in Django 1.8.

Comment: Yep, thanks. Been tearing my hair out trying to get an image to show over ajax...

Comment: /!\ Is deprecated, you should use TEMPLATE dict and the option context_processors : https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.9/ref/settings/#media-url

Comment: For the english speakers https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#media-url

Answer (score 30):

You need to add the `RequestContext` in your `render_to_response` for the context processors to be processed.

In your case:

```
from django.template.context import RequestContext

context = {'latest': p}
render_to_response('Question/latest.html',
                   context_instance=RequestContext(request, context))
```

From the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#optional-arguments):

> **context_instance**
>
> The context instance
> to render the template with. By
> default, the template will be rendered
> with a Context instance (filled with
> values from dictionary). If you need
> to use context processors, render the
> template with a RequestContext
> instance instead.

Comment: Awww thank you, I think they need to point that out better for people beginning django. MEDIA_URL is fairly important for design as well as portability.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use direct_to_template:

```
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
...
return direct_to_template(request, 'Question/latest.html', {'latest': p})
```

Comment: This will do the same thing as `render_to_response('Question/latest.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request, context))`?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to question provided above can suggest you to take a look at [photologue](http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/) application. It could help you to avoid direct links in template files and use objects instead.
F.ex.:

```
<img src="{{ artist.photo.get_face_photo_url }}" alt="{{ artist.photo.title }}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Update: For Django 1.10 users, the both media and static context processors are already moved in django.template from django.core read the following article for more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#django-template-context-processors-media