# Django: could not parse the remainder (media i.e. image)

Tags: django, django-templates, django-media

I am developing a WebApp using Django.I m a newbie, I have this html file which contains image, i did go through this ["link"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901551/how-do-i-include-image-files-in-django-templates), but now i am getting an error as in parsing the Media Url. Could any let me know what is wrong? I have checked the permissions, even they are correct. !!

This is that image which i am including -

```
<img border="2" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}samplelogo.jpg" alt="logo here"/>
```

This is the urls.py -

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
import settings

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^gharnivas/$', 'gharnivas.views.index'),
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
)
```

This is the settings.py with media url and root :

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/nagaraj/ghar/templates/media'
MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/media/'
```

**ghar is the django project and gharnivas is the app**

**Update** :

Now I have removed the error of TemplateSyntaxError by replacing Media url to '/media/' as suggested by @Torsten below. But still **not** getting the image !!

**Another query** , is it correct that i am using MEDIA_ROOT And MEDIA_URL ? Because some place i even see that they have STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT !!

Comment: I don't know if you're missing something, but we definitely are, because you haven't posted the template where you reference this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{ MEDIA_URL }}` outputs empty string? Make sure that

1). `'django.core.context_processors.media'` is in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`

2). You pass `RequestContext` in your template (by passing `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` in `render_to_response` or by using `direct_to_template` instead).

From Django 1.8 `'django.core.context_processors.media'` was moved to
`'django.template.context_processors.media'`

Comment: @DrTyrsa : I m confused towards your explanation. As i am a newbie with Django, I dint get your 1st point as to where can i add it? Even with my views.py i have got render_to_response('gharnivas/ghar.html') which loads the  first file but without the image .

Comment: `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` is in project's settigs.py. `'django.core.context_processors.media'` should be there by default.  This processor adds MEDIA_URL variable to your template. But you should use `RequestContext`. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756841/django-media-url-blank)'s the related question.

Comment: @DrTyrsa : I am sorry :(, not been able to find it in settings.py. I checked it throughly :|

Comment: That's strange, but if it isn't there you can place it there. Here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/settings/#template-context-processors you can find how it looks by default.

Comment: Should i add it by myself? I mean i didn't find any inbuilt TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS :|

Comment: Could u give ur mail id? because i will just mail u my entire settings.py file . As its freaking me out when i am not able to find it on my project folder :|

Answer (score 1):

`MEDIA_URL = '/media/'` instead of `MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/media/'`

Comment: I did change it, but still no progress. The fact is i had first written "http://localhost:8000/media/" because there was an example which was commented saying #Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"

Comment: My appologies, I had a small semicolon along with '/media/' . But even though the TemplateSyntaxError is removed. My media is still not been seen. I mean, i still dont get a image

Comment: As I can see your problem was somewhere else. Anyway, you'll never know how your project will change with time. If domain of you site is changing you are on the safe side just using `'/media/'`.