# django MEDIA_URL changes in child template?

Tags: django, url, path, media

I have these URLs in my project .urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^categories/', include('category.urls')),
)
```

In the categroy app, my category.urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('category.views',
    (r'^$', 'category_tree'),
    (r'^add/?$', 'category_add'),)
```

I have this in my settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = "http://localhost:80/media/"
ROOT_PATH = os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'templates'),
)
```

In the project templates directory there is a base template "base.html" with this line:

```
<link href="{{MEDIA_URL}}css/base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

In my "category" app, I also have templates "category_tree.html" and "category_add.html".
These both extend from base.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

The blocks in base.html are rendered correctly with content from these two child templates/views.
But the css and images of category_add.html aren't found.

There is a link on categroy_tree.html like this:

```
<div><a href="add">Add category</a></div>
```

This points to the correct view if clicked. But then the css MEDIA_URL request changes from

```
http://localhost/media/css/base.css
// (Correct)
```

to

```
http://localhost:8000/categories/css/base.css
// (Incorrect)
```

Why is this happening and what do I have to do to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure the template is printing `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` correctly? What does the link look like in the generated HTML? This question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756841/django-media-url-blank

Comment: Thanks Shawn see below, problem is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The add category view isn't using a RequestContext to render the page, so `MEDIA_URL` is not sent to the template context.

Comment: Indeed, that was simple! Thanks.