# Django can't see images in /media/ folder

Tags: python, django, image, templates

If I put my image in `/media/` folder, it doesn't works. But if I put them in '/static/' folder it works.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block contain %}
    <h1>New Report</h1>
    <form id="create" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Confirm">
    </form>


    {% for report in reports %}
        <P> {{report.title}} </P> <br>
        <img src="{{STATIC_URL}}<name of the image>" width='100px' height='100px'> =====> I can see the image

        <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}} <name of the image>" width='100px' height='100px'> =====> I cant see the image

        <img src="/static/<name of the image>" width='100px' height='100px'> =====> I cant see the image

        <img src="/media/<name of the image>" width='100px' height='100px'> ====>>>> I cant see the image


    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: How do you deploy your django app?

Comment: Have you read this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development

Comment: But my image is not a static file. My image is an image from my Report model. Whe I put an image in "Media" Folder i cant see the image, but when i use that image en my "Static" folder I can see the image. It's really weird.

Comment: it's a static file. Your Report model ImageField is just a link to that file. Check out my answer. Django or your webserver probably don't know about your media folder

Comment: If it's an image from your report model just call it directly and django will fill in the link for you.

Comment: I think that my server dont know about my media folder. I will check it.

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure django testing server (or apache/nginx) knows about your media folder?

Try to add this to urls.py (in case you're using development server):

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
   )
```

Comment: @Cris Towi, then, please accept the answer! Click this big check under vote score

Answer (score 0):

Putting images in your static folder will work, as the files in the static folder are served on the site. This is a potential solution and this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323686/how-can-i-get-the-media-url-from-within-a-django-template) seems to suggest it's reasonable for some images. On my site the images in the  media folder are located at `/uploads/<name of the image>`. This is what `MEDIA_URL` is set to. However I never explicitly call `MEDIA_URL` as all my images are tied into models so django handles that for me. My guess would be double check the name of the folder you're storing the images in and make sure you're looking at the right place. Second I would make sure that `{{MEDIA_URL}}` isn't [undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756841/django-media-url-blank) in the template.