# django media url tag

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Does django have `media` tag similar to `static` and `url` and how to setup it?

```
{% static 'styles/boo.css' %}
{% url 'some_app:some_name' %} 

Is this possible: {% media 'what here' %}?
```

How to setup it?

Comment: I got the same question, what is the solution?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need [`{% get_media_prefix %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#get-media-prefix).

The way to set it up is explained [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development): you have to set `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` in your settings and add `MEDIA_URL` to your `urls.py`.

Comment: If you use wagtail then load static templatetag first: `{% load static %}`

Comment: `{% load static %}` is not Wagtail-specific, it is a part of Django:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 57):

There is no media template tag.

Having set `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` you can use a media file in a template by referring to its `url` attribute.

For example:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(
        ...
    )
```

and then in your template:

```
<img src="{{ foo_object.image.url }}">
```

Also, take a look at the docs about [how to access media files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/files/#managing-files).

Comment: i have did same method the problem was 
django 3.2 i used my url ``` path('homes', include("page_home.urls"))``` only working but i want load image in index url  ```path('', include("page_home.urls"))```

Answer (score 12):

[{% get_media_prefix %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-get_media_prefix) and [{{MEDIA_URL}} via context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#django-template-context-processors-media) are both good alternatives for what you ask.

That being said, if what you really want to achieve is to render a link to an uploaded media file such as an image, there is a better way.

Model:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    logo = models.ImageField()

    @property
    def logo_url(self):
        if self.logo and hasattr(self.logo, 'url'):
            return self.logo.url
```

Template:

```
<img src="{{company.logo_url}}"/>
```

The reason for the @property is that you want to avoid cases where the ImageField doesn't contain an image. Accessing `company.logo.url` directly in the template will cause an exception in such a case.

This is actually a long standing issue in Django: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13327

Answer (score 3):

For media files I use `django-imagekit`
Basic use:

```
from django.db import models
from imagekit.models import ProcessedImageField
from imagekit.processors import ResizeToFill
```

models.py

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photos = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='pagename/images',
                                       processors=[ResizeToFill(900, 600)],
                                       format='JPEG',
                                       options={'quality': 90})
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'imagekit',
]
```

.html

```
{% load imagekit %}

{% thumbnail '100x50' source_file %}
```

Read documentation - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-imagekit