# Django - {{ MEDIA_URL }} not working as expected

Tags: python, django

I'm having a slight problem where my Django media tag isn't working properly.

This doesn't return the path I expect - which would be '`/media/uploads/image_name_goes_here/`', and instead I get '`/uploads/image_name_goes_here/`' even though I have specified in my settings.py that the `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`.

My `upload_to` path in the models for the Image is the following function..

```
def img_path(instance, filename):
    return ('uploads/%s' % (filename))

class Image(models.Model):
    ...
    image_url=models.ImageField(upload_to=img_path,null=True)
    ...
```

My html: `<img src='{{ MEDIA_URL }}/{{ Image.img_path }}'/>`

Any ideas on why the 'media/' bit of the URL does not show up?

Comment: Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35288916/2599940

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have MEDIA_URL in the context of your template; it's not there by default.

Note however that you don't need it, and you shouldn't be accessing the field like this. Use the `url` attribute:

```
<img src='{{ Image.img_url.url }}'>
```