# MEDIA_URL is empty in Django 1.4

Tags: django

I have read [Django {{ MEDIA_URL }} blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756841/django-media-url-blank) and [How do I include image files in Django templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901551/how-do-i-include-image-files-in-django-templates) questions but error still here: MEDIA_URL is empty in template.

My code:
settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = "D:/blizzard/Projects/Python/Web/moz455/app/media" # or os.path.join(SiteDir, "app/media")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'F:/Soft/Python26/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

views.py:

```
def gallery(request):
    ResponseDict = {}
    return render_to_response('gallery.html', ResponseDict, 
    context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^gallery/', gallery),
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
                 {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Can you show your template code? Have you included `django.core.context_processors.media` in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`?

Comment: Thank you, this was a solution, I forgot to do that.

Comment: I've added it as an answer so it can be closed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you have included `django.core.context_processors.media` in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
...
"django.core.context_processors.media",
...
)
```