# Media server on another host for django. Is it a right way?

Tags: python, django, nginx, shared-hosting

I read a lot of "how to do" a separate media server for Django. But I have own decision.

**/media** - dir on file server. I mount it to my django server(SSHFS), so I can save there user images, etc. Then I change **media_url** to `file server adress`/media, on file server I have **nginx**, which will hand out files.

Will it work this way?

Would it not be a big load on the django server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your server layout correctly — that nginx is running on your fileserver and it is proxying requests to Django on a different server, **it should work**. It would be best if the servers are in the same LAN or data center to reduce latency and network errors. You also want to make sure that the user that's running the nginx worker process has access to /media/.

Having nginx serve the media and static directories would reduce the load on your Django server. Gunicorn and uWSGI are highly regarded Django servers by the way.

It's a little unusual to use the /media/ directory as that's [usually reserved for CDROMs or USB flash drives](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/media.html). Usually `/var/www/example.com/media` or `/srv/www/example.com/media` are used.

## Settings

I just want to make sure you've got your domain set up properly because it affects how the MEDIA_URL setting is used especially if you serve Javascript from there so please bear with me. If your website is example.com, your DNS settings should point example.com to your nginx/fileserver IP address.

### Your Settings Files

**Django settings.py**

```
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

**nginx example.conf**

`root /;` looks scary in the following example but [have a look at the docs to verify this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root).

```
server {
    server_name example.com;

    location /media/ {
        root /;
    }

    # OTHER LOCATION RULES

    location / {
        # PROXY RULES HERE
    }
}
```

## Accessing Media Files

Your Django project can refer to your images using simple, absolute URLs like

```
<img src="/media/user1234/2012/03/04/aeiou.jpg" alt="aeiou">
```

or [use django.core.context_processors.media, RequestContext and {{ MEDIA_URL }}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756841/django-media-url-blank) just in case you move your media files to a CDN.

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/user1234/2012/03/04/aeiou.jpg" alt="aeiou">
```